# Is it possible to cache http resources ignoring query strings on client side?

Tags: http, cache-control

I'm curious if a client(e.g. a browser) can cache web content(e.g. an HTML file) ignoring query strings.
For example, a browser requests https://a.com/a.html?query=1, then requests https://a.com/a.html?query=2. Is it possible the browser just ignore "?query=2" and get result from cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would be able to do this, if you write a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) that takes advantage of the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'll try it.